# std::vector::erase for invalid ranges

Tags: c++, vector

I could not find in the documentation anything about `std::vector::erase` for ranges that are invalid(not empty, `erase` is are well defined for them), like `[end()+1, end())`. For example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.erase(std::find(b.begin(), v.end(), 9001) + 1, v.end());
```

Is this code safe to use to remove the elements after one specific element or is it necessary to check if `std::find` returned something `!= v.end()`?

Comment: No, of course it isn't.

Comment: If you like undefined behaviour, it's totally fine. If there's one thing C++ will quickly teach you, though, it's that you want to steer well away from that sort of thing. Always check that you're not setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: Adding 1 to `end()` will put you in the realm of undefined behaviour before you even try to use it in `erase`.

Comment: Indeed. C++11 Table 107, if you're interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

in Exception safety:

> [..] An invalid position or range causes undefined behavior.

So no, the code is not safe.

Comment: Cool, thanks! This is I wanted to find:) I will accept the answer when it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
v.erase(std::find(b.begin(), v.end(), 9001) + 1, v.end());
```

You have to make sure `find` doesn't return `end()` as in that case range would be invalid [end()+1, end()] which is undefined behavior.

However, if you do following then you are well outside undefined behavior realm.

```
v.erase(std::find(b.begin(), v.end(), 9001), v.end());
```